# RHEL: Timezone change affected processes

Tags: redhat, time, timezone

I'm having troubles by a recent time zone change (the time went an hour back).
Even though using the date command returns the correct time and date, i'm having trouble with programs that use log4j (it has the old time) and crontabs are not starting on time.

I tried restarting crontab and all processes that were using log4j and the problem still persists. By checking some log4j logs I noticed that it is using the old time.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm of the persuasion that you have two separate issues plaguing you.

### First, log4j

Check your java version and make sure that it's the latest version. You may be in need of time zone updates that are in the latest patch.

### Second, cron

I've seen similar things happen in Debian/Ubuntu, and it was simply a bug in cron that had to wait for a patch. Make sure that your version of cron is up to date (hopefully you're using RH repos).

Comment: hi, can you please provide more information on how to install time zone updates to java? i researched online and there is a tool called tzupdater which does this, but the latest version is 2011n and i need to install patch 2012b

Comment: @nmuntz That would be a new issue outside of the scope of this question. We prefer that each question and answer be tightly scoped to the problem at hand, so I think you would get more and better answers if you made a new question concerning how to update java timezones using tzupdater.